# How can I install Pytorch in VS code on Windows?

Tags: visual-studio-code, pytorch

```
(studysession) C:\Users\Steven\PyTorch>pip install torch
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch
```

Do I need to downgrade to Python 3.7.?

Comment: PyTorch? In VSCode? Do you mean as an extension? Or do you mean the PyTorch package? The one pip serves on its repository?

Comment: Whatever, I just want to use PyTorch in VS code.

Comment: running into this issue myself, will comeback to post if I figure it out

Answer (score 0):

From the project page on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/torch/#data), it says it requires: Python >=3.8.0. So upgrade your python version if it isn’t upgraded. Open a terminal, then run `pip install torch`.

**Advice**: run this in a virtual environment instead of globally.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the [get-started page](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) of pytorch, select the proper language and compute platform, then copy the command and install pytorch to your computer.

Attention: If you use global python interpreter, pytorch will be installed globally, which could be risky. So the better way is to use `conda` or `pip` to create a virtual python environment and then install pytorch in it.

After the installation of pytorch, you need to install the `python` plugin in vscode. Then you can get the pytorch autocompletion in vscode after you choose the proper python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Your python version is likely not supported yet

try

pip3 install --pre torch -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cpu/torch_nightly.html